# Keeping get_posts' offset and is_paged() synchronized

Tags: query-posts, offsets

I am developing the blog-template of my theme, which works as following: The user can input the total post-count to display on each blog-page (`$blogpost_count`). The blog itself lists post-entries in two different fashions, like so:

- first, the newest X (X being equal to $blogpost_count) posts are listed regularly with query_posts,
- then, the following 2 posts are listed with get_posts and an offset equal to `$blogpost_count`.

Now, the different between both fashions/queries is merely CSS. Meaning, the first list of posts has a certain style, and the second another style. Furthermore, the second list is always offset by the specified `$blogpost_count`, essentially displaying the adjacent posts - if available.

**Here's my issue:** This methodology works flawlessly on the first blog page. However, when the user navigates back to view older posts (i.e. with `next_posts_link()`, ending up on an `is_paged()` blog page), the offset does not "adjust" to the new number of displayed posts. Because of `'offset' => $blogpost_count`, that variable still applies on e.g. the second blog page, even if there is only 1 post listed.

My logic tells me what I need something like this (simplified):

```
if(!is_paged()) { 
    'offset' => $blogpost_count;
} else {
    'offset' => $number_of_currently_displayed_posts_PLUS_off_all_newer_posts;
}
```

I hope I explained myself thoroughly.
Thank you!

**EDIT:** You can view [a static HTML example of the blog-template](http://demo.crozer.me/era/blog.html), to hopefully, visually understand my concept better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if(!is_paged()) {      
    $post_offset = $blogpost_count; 
} else {     
    $post_offset = (get_query_var('paged')-1)*2+$blogpost_count; 
} 

...
...
   'offset' => $post_offset;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This works beautifully. However, there's one minor drawback, and that is, making the previous/next_posts_link(s) understand how and what we're offsetting. This is my current code: http://pastie.org/3005879 - please read the comments for further understanding. That code solves the: non-paged and paged more-posts being properly offset AND the paged regular posts being also properly offset.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - answered to myself to soon. My solution partially fixed the offset, but it caused other issues. That said, my issue remains and I truly appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you!